# "Too old to work with working copy" error with SVN in Mac OS X

Tags: svn, macos

I've had this before and followed these instructions http://www.redfinsolutions.com/redfin-blog/update-subversion-mac-os-x. However today I am trying to do a 'status' and then 'commit', however I'm now getting the same error of:

```
svn: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'; please get a newer Subversion client
```

Which is obviously right because when I do a `svn --version` it says it is `1.4.4`.

Comment: "which svn" should tell you where that old svn is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You previously accessed this working copy with a newer client (maybe eclipse plugin?). 
The newer svn client updates the workingcopy to the new version.

All older clients cannot access your working copy anymore.

You should follow the advice and update to a new SVN client (1.4.4 is *very* old)

If you cannot upgrade avod accessing your workingcopy with SVN clients of different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Update to newer client. Backward compatibility is lost between 1.4, 1.5, 1.6

> Blockquote
>   svn, version 1.6.9 (r901367)
>      compiled May 25 2010, 09:12:11